# Error: shape '[-1, 270000]' is invalid for input of size 1440000

Tags: pytorch

I got an error:

> shape '[-1, 270000]' is invalid for the input of size 1440000

while running my  code for a CNN structure input tensor size is 64.

```
Class MyNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyNet, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 48, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(48, 108, 2)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(108, 192, 2)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(192, 300, 2)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(300* 30* 30, 864)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(864, 288)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(288, 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv4(x))
        #x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv4(x)))
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = x.view(-1, 300 * 30* 30)   
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x)
```

Any idea why I am getting above error?

Answer (score 0):

Because after your max pooling layer, the shape of feature map is `(300, width, height)`, and `300*width*height != 300*30*30`. If you want to reshape the tensor, you must keep the same number of elements.

Comment: thank you for your reply. can you please help me out to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

The view operation which should flatten x is throwing this error, since the size of `300*30*30` is not matching your activation size. Most likely your custom dataset has a different spatial size, such that the view is failing.

Based on the shape given in the error message, it looks like your activation should have the shape `[batch_size=3, channels=300, height=40, width=40]`, which results in `1440000` values. Try to change the input size in your linear layer to `300*40*40` like this:

```
self.fc1 = nn.Linear(300*40*40, 864)
```

and the flattening to:

```
x = x.view(x.size(0), 300*40*40)
```

Please, notify me if this doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is still occurring, can you please share with me how this width n height is coming after the pooling layer. actually, I need three consecutive convolution layer followed by a pooling layer.

Comment: But, above in your code, there are four consecutive conv layers followed by a pooling layer. Isn't it?

Comment: can you please tell me the value of `x.size(0)` after applying pooling layer in above code, i.e., batch_size ?

Comment: batch-size is 4

Comment: Please, try by replacing self.fc1 = nn.Linear(300* 30* 30, 864) with self.fc1 = nn.Linear(360000, 864), if batch_size=4 and x = x.view(x.size(0), 300*40*40) with x = x.view(x.size(0), 360000)

Comment: And, if this doesnot work, then please add full code, so that I can reproduce the same error. What's the image size? It's 64x64x3 ?